# ¿Porque cuando agrego un icono de font awesome a una caja de texto el icono solo me muestra un rectangulo?

Tags: css, html5, font-awesome

Actualmente quisiera agregar un `icono` dentro de mi `textfield` para que el usuario pueda visualizar algo relacionado con lo que representa el campo.

Codigo de html:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="&#xf075; Add Comment" id="txtnombre_promotor" />
```

Codigo de css:

```
#txtnombre_promotor {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f007";
}
```

Ya inclui en mi index.php la referencia a `fontawesome` y es la version `4.7.0`

Resultado actual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el problema puede deberse al place holder, ya que si yo quito el codigo .css sigue viendose el rectangulo en mi caja de texto y creo que se debe alcodigo que ingrese en el textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente funciona bien, ¿o acaso es otro el resultado esperado?

```css
#txtnombre_promotor {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f007";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="&#xf075; Add Comment" id="txtnombre_promotor" />
```

Comment: a mi me no me sale el icono que te sale y lo tengo en tu mismo orden, de hecho actualice el post con una foto de lo que me sale a mi.

Comment: ¿Tal vez sea otro código CSS que lo daña? No se me ocurre como más reproducir el problema. ¿codificación?

Comment: lo modifique, en vez de un icono  agregue una imagen, gracias por responder.